# How to draw symmetry lines/planes as in chemical formulas?

Tags: diagrams, forest

How I can draw these "orange" lines, that show the symmetry, as in a chemical formula?
And, can I write a word (instead of a symbol) in a chemical formula, for example, instead of `C` how to write the word `Center`?

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Edit:

---

What I have is something like this (not a chemical formula):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [{($vp_{type}$, \{$T$\})} [{$v_{directed}$}] [{$v_{undirected}$}]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

But, I wanted to draw lines over it like in the chemical formula, and if this is possible / easy to make by using the chemical packages than I'm fine to switch on them but I haven't used that package before and I couldn't write (without overlapping) words instead of symbols :/

Thanks!!!

Comment: How do you make the formula in the first place?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. , I added an edit, with what I have. Thanks!

Comment: So, your question doesn't really have anything to do with chemistry, you just want to draw some arrows in a tree made by `forest`? Where does "write `Center` instead `C`" come in?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. If I keep using the `forest` then it's OK, the problem is solved about the `C` and `Center`. But, in a chemical formula (which is OK not to use it at all) I couldn't write it as the words were overlapping and the lines between were not being adjusted to fit them well. Btw, my problem is not related with chemistry - I just saw that they need these "orange" lines over their formulas quite often, and I thought that might be an easy way to do it, as I'm needing them too for my case.

Comment: The chemistry thing is really misleading here as my first, second and third thoughts were all, 'don't use Forest!'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw stuff by using normal TikZ commands just before `\end{forest}`. For positioning, you can for example give a `name` to one or more of the nodes in the tree, and draw lines relative to that.

[image: arrows in trees]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{
  MyArrow/.style={->,orange,dashed,thick}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[
  {($vp_{\text{type}}$, \{$T$\})}, name=a
    [{$v_{\text{directed}}$}]
    [{$v_{\text{undirected}}$}]
]
  \draw [MyArrow] (a.south) ++(0,-1.5) -- ++(0,2.5);
  \draw [MyArrow] (a.south) ++(-2,-0.25) -- ++(4,0);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, this is what I was thinking of. I understand how you have done, now :) Thanks a lot!!!